# How to avoid duplicates of records in a field In standard Object using flows or Validation rules or flow builder

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, flow-builder

For a Product standard object, I would like to avoid duplicates in the Product Name field and Product code field. How can I achieve this using validation rules, flows, or flow builder? Please provide me with the best and most reliable solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use custom text field and make it a unique. You can make a field unique on the following custom fields: Text, Phone, and Email.

Answer (score 0):

- Validation Rules - not possible as they can't look across records.
- Normally, one would use Duplicate Rules but these aren't supported on `Product2` object (as of Winter 23)
- Normal second option is to make `Product2.Name` an external Id but as this is an OOTB field, this is not supported

This leaves you with an external Id / unique "shadow" custom text field that is not shown on the layout.

- Use a before Save Flow with an Assignment element to copy `$Record.Name` to the shadow field.
- When the save operation on an insert or update of a Product2 occurs, the DML commit will fail if the shadow field is the same as any other Product2 record already in the database.